# Почему я получаю ошибку 500 от сервера при запросе данных для построения графика?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, http-status-code-500

У меня есть компонент **v-customQA** где  прописана вся логика для запроса данных с сервера.
После заполнения всех полей делается запрос на получение и отрисовку данных. Вылетает ошибка 500, не могу понять, что я не так делаю. Отдельный компонент **home**, в котором с помощью табов я переключаю вкладки управляет логикой переключения.  Компонент **v-header-forms** , в нем прописана логика всех полей( select, input, checkbox ). Через mapstate я обращаюсь к модулю в хранилище ( к данным ). Вот код:

```
error Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:62)
```

**home**

```
<template>
  <v-header-forms />
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="container with-nav" >
            <ul class="tab-nav">
                <li class="tab-nav-item">
                    <a
                        @mouseover="active = true"
                        @mouseleave="active = false"
                        @click="changeTab(1)"
                        class="tab-link"
                        :class="{active: activeTab === 1}"
                    >Recommended</a>
                </li>

                <li class="tab-nav-item">
   
                    <a
                        @click="changeTab(3)"
                        class="tab-link"
                        :class="{active: activeTab === 3}"
                    >Custom QA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div
             class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-item" v-if="activeTab === 1 && $store.state.calculator.selectedUnderlying && $store.state.calculator.selectedMaturity && $store.state.calculator.coinAmount">
                    <v-recommended></v-recommended>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-item" v-if="activeTab === 2">
                    <v-customPro></v-customPro>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-item" v-if="activeTab === 3">
                    <vCustomQa></vCustomQa>
                </div>
</template>
<script>
data() {
        return {
            active: false,
            activeTab: 1,
            langList: ["RU", "EN"],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeTab(value) {
            console.log('setting', value)
            this.activeTab = value
            this.$store.commit('calculator/clearForm')
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

**v-customQA**

```
<vSelect
          v-model="selectedDirection"
          :options="directionOptions"
          @input="setDirection"
        >
        </vSelect>
<vLineChart2
        v-if="chartData"
        class="text-left chart-v min-w-2/3 w-2/3 mt-5"
        :dataset="chartData"
      />
            <input
              class="input border border-gray-400   rounded px-3 py-3  pb-2    "
              v-model="max_slippage"
              name="inputSlipage"
              id="slipage"
              type="number"
            />
<script>
computed: {
    requestParams() {
      return {
        main_direction: this.selectedDirection,
        fut_hedge_flag: this.convertBooleanToString(this.subDirectionFlag),
        sub_direction_flag: this.convertBooleanToString(this.saveDirection),
        main_range: 0,
        sub_range: [...this.expectedMaxPrice],
        max_slippage: this.max_slippage,
      };
    },
    markSliderCoin() {
      switch (this.selectedCoin) {
        case "BTC":
          return this.markSlider;
        case "ETH":
          return this.markSliderEth;

        default:
          return null;
      }
    },

    ...mapGetters(["fullDataList", "tableList"]),

    ...mapState({
      selectedCoin: (state) => state.calculator.selectedUnderlying,
      selectedDate: (state) => state.calculator.selectedMaturity,
      coinAmount: (state) => state.calculator.coinAmount,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      "getMaturity_actions",
      "getStrikes_actions",
      "getQaStructs_actions",
      "sendOrder",
    ]),

    async getMaturity(underlying) {
      this.maturityList = await this.getMaturity_actions(underlying);
      const result = await this.getStrikes_actions(this.selectedCoin); //BTC-ETH
      console.log(".main_value", result[this.selectedCoin].main_value);
      console.log("sub_value", result[this.selectedCoin].sub_value);
      this.minSlider = result[this.selectedCoin].min;
      this.maxSlider = result[this.selectedCoin].max;
      this.stepSlider = result[this.selectedCoin].step;
      this.expectedMinPrice = [...result[this.selectedCoin].main_value];
      this.defolt_expectedMinPrice = [...result[this.selectedCoin].main_value];
      this.expectedMaxPrice = [...result[this.selectedCoin].sub_value];
      this.defolt_expectedMaxPrice = [...result[this.selectedCoin].sub_value];
      /* this.setupSliderLabels();   */
      this.selectedDate = null;
      this.coinAmount = 0;
      this.chartData = null;
      this.max_slippage = null;
      this.tableData = null;
      this.selectedDirection = null;
      this.futHedgeFlag_top = false;
      this.futHedgeFlag_down = false;
      this.saveDirection = false;
      this.subDirectionFlag = false;
      this.markSlider = (v) => !(v % 25000);
      this.markSliderEth = (v) => !(v % 1000);
    },

    setupSliderLabels() {
      this.sliderLabels = [];
      const labelsAmount = 15;
      const labelStep = Math.ceil(this.maxSlider / labelsAmount / 100) * 100;
      let currentLabel = 0;
      for (let index = 0; index < labelsAmount; index++) {
        this.sliderLabels.push(currentLabel);
        currentLabel = currentLabel + labelStep;
      }
    },

    setMaturity(event) {
      this.$store.commit("setMaturity_mutations", event);
    },

    convertBooleanToString(flag) {
      return (
        String(flag)
          .charAt(0)
          .toUpperCase() + String(flag).slice(1)
      );
    },

    async setDirection(value) {
      console.log("setDirection");
      this.selectedDirection = value;
      let shit = 0;
      clearInterval(this.intervalTimerId);
      this.intervalTimerId = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          const result = await this.$store.dispatch(
            "getQaStructs_actions",
            this.requestParams
          );
          console.log("result-setDirection", result);
          if (result) {
            shit++;
            if (shit === 1) {
              this.chartData = result[0].chart;
            }
            this.tableData = result[0].table;
            if (!this.max_slippage) {
              this.max_slippage = result[0].max_slippage;
            }
            console.log("max_slippage", this.max_slippage);
            console.log("chartData", this.chartData);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("catch", error);
        }
      }, 2000);

      /*       console.log("tableData", this.tableData); */
    },

    setAmount(selectedDirection) {
      this.$store.commit("setAmount_mutations", selectedDirection);
    },

    async FieldsCheck() {
      if (
        this.selectedCoin &&
        this.selectedDate &&
        this.coinAmount != 0 &&
        this.selectedDirection
      ) {
        this.setDirection();
      }
    },

    changeMinPrice() {
      this.futHedgeFlag_top = false;
    },

    changeMaxPrice() {
      this.futHedgeFlag_down = false;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  },
</script>
```

**calculator.js** (модуль sotre.js)

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        selectedUnderlying: null,
        selectedMaturity: null,
        coinAmount: 0,
        hedgeFunding: false,

        maturityList: {
            btc: [],
            eth: []
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        setUnderlying(state, value) {
            state.selectedUnderlying = value
        },
        setMaturity(state, value) {
            state.selectedMaturity = value
        },
        setCoinAmount(state, value) {
            state.coinAmount = value
        },
        setHedgeFunding(state, value) {
            state.hedgeFunding = value
        },

        clearForm(state) {
            state.selectedUnderlying = null
            state.selectedMaturity = null
            state.coinAmount = 0
            state.hedgeFunding = false
        }
    }
}
```

**store.js**

```
     actions: {
    async getStrikes_actions(context) {
          try {
            const url = "/strikes";
            const options = {
              params: {
                currency: context.rootState.calculator.selectedUnderlying,
              },
            };
    
            const response = await axios.get(url, options);
            return response.data.data;
          } catch (error) {
            return false;
          }
        },
    
        async getQaStructs_actions(context, params) {
          console.log("params", params);
          try {
            const url = `/qaStructs?currency=${context.rootState.calculator.selectedUnderlying}&maturity=${context.rootState.calculator.selectedMaturity}&amount=${context.rootState.calculator.coinAmount}&fut_hedge_flag=${params.fut_hedge_flag}&main_direction=${params.main_direction}&main_range=${params.main_range}&sub_direction_flag=${params.sub_direction_flag}&sub_range=${params.sub_range}&max_slippage=${params.max_slippage}`;
            console.log("url",url);
            let response = await axios.get(url);
    
            console.log("response",response);
            return response.data.data;
          }
          
           catch (error) {
            console.log("error",error);
            return false;
          }
        },
    },
getters: {
    maturityList: (state) => state.maturityList,
    fullDataList: (state) => state.fullDataList,
    underlyingChoice: (state) => state.underlying,
    tableList: (state) => state.key,
    maturity: (state) => state.maturity,
  },

  modules: {
    auth,
    calculator
  },
```

Comment: ответ очевиден: на сервере происходит какая-то ошибка

Comment: До этого логика работала, тут дело в чем-то другом. Я что-то не правильно передаю на запросе.

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что ошибка происходит на сервере, и что именно сломалось нужно смотреть там.

Comment: добавьте скрин с нетворка